# HTML option selects first default value instead of choosen value

Tags: php, html

Whenever I Select any other options in my drop down I am still getting the first value which is '?' instead of any of the other ones I picked.

```
<select name="role"  class="form-control">  
     <option value="?" label ="Please Select a Role" id="role">Select a Role</option>
        <?PHP foreach($roles as $role){ ?>
            <option value= "<?=$role['id']?>" label=" <?=$role['role']?>"><?=$role['role']?>
            </option>
        <?PHP } ?>
</select>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the HTML look like when the page is run? In browser, right click and choose `"View Page Source"`

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake
The reason I was not getting getting any other values was because I was getting the ID of the first option so it would retrieve the same value each time

I solved it by moving the value of Id to the first select tag

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are pulling the value off whatever DOM element has an `id` of `role`. In this case, you've defined an `option` that always has the `id` `role`.